# If there is a non-constructible real, is there an $L$-generic real?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

If we assume that $\Bbb R^V\neq\Bbb R^L$, can we deduce that there is some $x\in\Bbb R^V$ which is $L$-generic?

Of course if $V$ is a generic extension of $L$ this is true, but if $V=L[0^\#]$ this is also true (the existence of $0^\#$ implies the existence of $L$-Cohen generics), but $0^\#$ cannot be added by forcing. So it is possible to have reals which are not generic over $L$, but their existence does imply that a generic exist.

Is this always the case, or is there a counterexample? Namely, can we have $V=L[x]$ for some real number $x$ such that no real number in $L[x]$ is $L$-generic?

*Edit:* As Joel's answer shows, we can generate a counterexample using class forcing over $L$. To avoid these, we might as well require that the universe is not a class-generic extension of some $W$ for which $\Bbb R^W=\Bbb R^L$.

Comment: My knowledge of generics is pretty weak, but from the bit of recursion theory I know, and what I know of the analogies, it seems like some version of the usual means for constructing reals of intermediate degree ought to provide such an $x$?

Comment: Hi Asaf - I came across this old question while researching other things, and I'm very intrigued by your side comment in the question above, that the existence of 0# implies the existence of L-Cohen generics.  Could you provide a reference?  Many thanks!

Comment: @jonasreitz: That's easy. If $0^\#$ exists, then $\omega_1^L$ is countable, therefore $\operatorname{Add}(\omega,1)^L$ has only countably many dense open sets (in $L$), so there is a generic filter meeting them. The same argument holds for any $V$-countable $L$-cardinal.

Comment: (Also, as a side note, `\#` produces $\#$, just for future reference. So you wanted to write $0^\#$, @jonasreitz.)

Comment: Thanks, Asaf - that’s great!  Do you know if it holds for cardinals not countable in $V$?  I don’t see immediately how to generalize the argument, but it would be great if $L[0^\#]$ had L-generics for all posets $Add(\kappa,1)^L$.   (Ps. Thanks also for the markup advice - I’m posting from my phone so we’ll see how it comes out).

Comment: @jonasreitz: Well, if I understand correctly, then yes. If $\kappa$ is a cardinal in $V$, then $\operatorname{Add}(\kappa,1)^L$ is an $L$-$\kappa$-closed forcing, which only has $\kappa$ many subsets, so you should be able to construct generics. If my memory serves me even better, Solovay proved that from $0^\#$ there is a class generic for a class forcing over $L$ which violates GCH on a proper class of cardinals. I imagine that was the sort of arguments used...

Comment: Wonderful - yes, that’s exactly what I’m looking for.  I’ll think through the argument and do some looking into Solovays result, too.  Many thanks - this is a big help!

Comment: @jonas: I don't know the exact reference. But if that helps, I know that in Grigorieff's treasure trove of a paper "Intermediate Submodels and Generic Extensions" he mentions that result on page 471.

Answer (score 9):

Great question!

In order to formalize the notion, let us understand the phrase "$x$ is $L$-generic" to mean: there is some partial order $\mathbb{P}\in L$ and some filter $G\subset\mathbb{P}$ that is $L$-generic, such that $x\in L[G]$. In particular, this refers to set-sized forcing only.

In this case, we can give a negative answer. Sy Friedman has a way to undertake the [coding-the-universe forcing](http://books.google.com/books/about/Coding_the_Universe.html?id=WiA4AAAAIAAJ) in such a way that the generic extension $V[G]=L[R]$ is minimal: [Minimal Coding, Annals of Pure and Applied Logic, 1989, pp. 233-297](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~sdf/papers/minimal.coding.pdf). In particular, every real in the extension is either in $V$, or generates $R$, which is not set-generic (although it is generic for class forcing). Thus, if you start in $L$ and then undertake this forcing, you get a class forcing extension in which there are no $L$-generic reals for set forcing, and indeed, no $L$-generic sets of any kind.

In the linked paper, Friedman states the following:

**Corollary.** There is an $L$-definable forcing for producing a real $R$ which is minimal over $L$ but not set-generic over $L$.

It follows that this extension $L[R]$ has no set-generic objects at all not in $L$. That is, it is a strong counterexample, which applies not just to reals, but to sets of any size.

Comment: That sure answers the question, thanks! Now comes the obvious follow up, what if we allow class-generics?

Comment: Well, that seems far more difficult.  First, it cannot really be formalized in ZFC. Second, if you forbid class forcing, then our hands are too-much tied for building a counterexample.

Comment: Sy has also studied a concept of hyperclass forcing, but I don't know whether it provides a counterexample for the follow-up question. If it does, then there's an obvious further follow-up.

Comment: Joel, here's a slightly more sensitive follow up. Can we characterize (except trivially) models of the form $L[x]$ where $x$ is a real number, in which there are no $L$-generic reals?

Comment: I seriously doubt there will be a good characterization of such models, since the coding-the-universe argument shows that any model $V$ is a ground model of such an $L[x]$. So our characterization will have to include in some a way an account of all possible $V$'s.

Comment: Hmm. I see your point, and it feels that (especially after a recent question) a "rapidly changing" question is not in place here. But I can't help and wonder if one can ask about inner models. That is, rephrase the question. Given $V$ such that $\Bbb R^V\neq\Bbb R^L$, is there an inner model $W$ and $x\in\Bbb R^W$ such that $W=L[x]$ is a generic extension of $L$? (But I don't really expect this to have a reasonable answer. Just throwing it out there!)

Comment: Oops, my previous comment is wrong, since $V$ could easily have $L$-generics....I had neglected that part of your question...

Comment: I'll unaccept for now, then. But I'm hoping to see a revision! :-)

Comment: Oh, I had just meant my remark about your classification follow-up question. I think my answer is correct for your question, since as I say there, we should start in L.

Comment: Wait, if we have that $V=L[c]$ for a Cohen real $c$, then we encode this using Sy's class forcing. We have $L[R]$, but $c\in L[R]$ and $c$ is still $L$-generic. (As a side note, due to Andreas' comment I am not being pinged automatically, if it's not too much trouble, please ping me in the next comments!)

Comment: The point is that Sy's forcing only gives minimality over V, not over L. So if we start with V=L, then we get the desired counterexample for your question.

Comment: Ah. I see! But now the restriction over class forcing makes slightly more sense, I think (and I mean, who encodes the universe when it's $L$? :-)).

Comment: Well, in this case point wasn't to code the universe, but to add a real that wasn't set-generic over $L$, while also adding no other set-generic sets. This is, after all, what you asked for...

Comment: Again, I agree. But this example feels like "the trivial counterexample which I wanted to neglect anyway". If one is so inclined, then I can modify my question to say whether or not $V\neq L[A]$ for any set $A$ implies that there is an $L$-generic real; but this will also miss a big point (that there are plenty of interesting models of the form $L[A]$). Instead, I suppose, I can just require that $V$ is not a class forcing generic extension of any $V$ for which $\Bbb R^V=\Bbb R^L$.

Comment: I don't really understand the objection, since Sy's model seems to answer the opening question of your post negatively, and it certainly isn't trivial.

Comment: I'll get back to you after I get some sleep (if that is ever going to happen, although it's unlikely to happen soon). I think that I'm too sleep deprived to decide anything right now. But at the moment I feel that the example is *good*, but misses the point I was trying to understand.